# Removing SSH key for user / i.p. address to server running OpenSSH/sshd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssh, sshd, ssh-keys

I recently had some issues with upgrading my distro to the latest LTS and allowed my local admin to log into my laptop via ssh, using my username and gave them root access.

While this was helpful, I'd like to secure my machine by preventing ssh access to my ssh.

- Is it possible to locate the ssh key created for this user and delete it?
- Will this prevent any further access?
- Where are clients ssh keys stored?

I've looked around a bit, and it seems that editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and uncommenting `PermitRootLogin no` is one solution, but seems to preclude me from logging in myself and getting root access in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things here, first off you can delete the user with

```
sudo userdel -r <username>
```

Secondly the private key is stored in ~/.ssh/identity, thats on his machine(assuming he's using unix/linux based systems) and not your problem. The public key is stored in ~/.ssh/identity.pub so when you delete his user account, the -r flag will also remove his home directory including his .ssh directory. The public key must be placed in /root/.ssh/authorized_keys of the remote machine in order for the setup to work. So make sure his keys have been removed there as well.

Lastly, you should make the changes you mentioned above anyways. PermitRootLogin only pertains to ssh access. If you set it to no, you ssh in with your user account, then `sudo su` and bam your root. Which is how you should have it set up anyways.

I'd also advise you make some additional changes for better SSH security.

**Setup for both public key and password**

Edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. Add the following line in the file:

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,password
```

**Warning: Make sure the the PasswordAuthentication looks like:**

```
#PasswordAuthentication yes
```

This will require the user has a working user account and password, and a public key on the box to ssh in.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer.   `Couple things here, first off you can delete the user with ....` - unfortunately, the admin used my own username to log into my machine, so I'm not sure about removing 'me' from the list of allowed users. Since they were the last person to ssh into my machine, so would a solution be deleting the last created public key in `~/.ssh/identity.pub` and `/root/ssh/authorized_keys`?                     Otherwise, I'll make the other changes you suggested.

Comment: Yes, remove whatever key he used, change your user password, and then make the other changes I suggested. Including generating a new set of ssh keys for your user.

Comment: @nonreligious please mark my answer as correct if it solved your problem.